# MySql procedure for multidimentional array loop

Tags: mysql, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, procedure

Anyone can help me for the question is highly appreciated.

I have a list of tables, say t1,t2,t3.....

The table names stored in an array

```
tname=("t1","t2",...."tn")
```

I also have parameters, they could be two-dimensional arrays, one dimensional array

```
p1=( (1,2,3),(3,4,5))
p2=('2020-01-01', '2020-02-01',....'2020-12-01')
```

I want to build a stored procedure to accept those parameters and save the results in to a table

Say I will call the procedure like this

```
CALL myproc(tname, p1,p2);
```

inside `myproc`, I will loop through those arrays and run procedures and store the result into a two-dimensional array table, then load the results into a database table or return the two dimensional array results from myproc.

For example insider myproc there will be a SQL statement like (pseudo sql string here)

```
/*two dimensional for loop*/
for i=1 to 2
  for k=1 to 3
     /*return a result_row as an row from a SQL call below*/
     DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEMPT;
     CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMPT(ID INT UNSIGNED auto_increment primary key, X VARCHAR(24));
     INSERT INTO TEMPT(A.x) SELECT A.x FROM tname[i] AS A WHERE A.date=p2[k] AND A.y=p1[i,k];
     /*Then insert the result_row in to a table T;*/
     ,,,,,,
  next k
next i
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEMPT;
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't have arrays.

Comment: You can emulate 1-dimensional arrays by using comma-delimited strings and `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`. But that won't work for 2-dimensional arrays. You can use tables for N-dimensional arrays -- the first N columns are the indexes, and the last column is the value.

Comment: Hmm, if you find yourself using loops to select from different tables that yet share the same or part of the same structure there is a high likelihood your design is flawed and the different tables should really be just one or the respective parts of them should be united in just one table.